# Generic classes within Drools-WorkBench

Tags: java, drools

I am currently working on a project that require that the input into Drools-Workbench for validation up against, is Generic.

So in essence what should be happening is the following;

1. receive object from an RabbitMQ channel.
2. Validate object with Drools-WB.
3. Upload the validation results (obtained from Drools-WB) to a RabbitMQ channel.

I have the following class, wherein the `input` is the "generic part", and the `ruleSet` should specify which rulesheet should be used from the Drools-WB instance.

```java
public class InputObject {


    private Integer primaryKey;

    private Integer sessionId;

    private Integer transactionId;

    private String ruleSet;

    private Map<String, Object> input;

    private List<ValidationResult> validationResults;
    public void addValidationResult(ValidationResult validationResult) {
        this.validationResults.add(validationResult);
    }
    // [...]
}
```

This is submitted to my Drools-WB instance using `KieServicesClient` for JAVA, using the following commands:

```java
KieCommands commandFactory = kieServices.getCommands();
commands.add(commandFactory.newInsert(inputObject, "ValRes"));
commands.add(commandFactory.newFireAllRules());

BatchExecutionCommand batchExecutionCommand = commandFactory.newBatchExecution(commands, conf.getKieSession());

ServiceResponse<ExecutionResults> response = this.createRulesClient()
        .executeCommandsWithResults(inputObject.getRuleSet(), batchExecutionCommand);
ExecutionResults singleRes = response.getResult();
```

The rules are specified in .xlsx file, such that it should be possible for "non-technical" people to submit rules, "more easily".
Currently the following rules are applied;
[image: An xlsx sheet with one rule and one condition]
Though with this configuration a null exceptions is always thrown, no matter how I assigns values to the `input` variable.

Besides this, I tried to simply have a new object inherit from LinkedHashMap, like so;

```java
public class DroolsObject extends LinkedHashMap<String, Object> {


    public void addValidationResult(ValidationResult validationResult) {
        if (!this.containsKey("validationResult"))
            this.put("validationResult", new LinkedList<ValidationResult>());
        ((List<ValidationResult>) this.get("validationResult")).add(validationResult);
    }
}
```

Where `input` is simply an instance of this `DroolsObject` class.
With this configuration, it is possible to utilize the keyword `this` within the Drools .xlsx sheet, like this;
[image: A simple ruleset, like the previous, just utilizing the keyword "this"]

But with this configuration, the rules are just executed, and no matter the value of DyrAlder the rule is not triggered.

I know that the function `addValidationResult` works in this context, as I've managed to receive a result, when I create a class where the variables tested on is given pr. default.

So my question is this;
I've not really found anything related to generalizing the Drools class, so I hope to get some answers if I'm SOL with this approach, or if there is another way of doing this?
Maybe having a HashMap that I'm sending to the Drools-WB, and then just overwriting the class, so that it can use a specific class specified in the Drools-WB repository.

Anyway, happy holidays, and thanks in advance for taking your time in answering this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce NullPointerException for the first example only when I inserted objects without proper initialization. For the second case, indeed, `this["DyrAlder"] < $param` doesn't work, but `this.get("DyrAlder") < $param`, `this.DyrAlder < $param` and even `DyrAlder < $param` works for me.

According to your description I complicated your rules with desired `ruleSet` parameter to get working POC for your requirements. Out of 10 objects being inserted, only 5 fit condition `DyrAlder < 5` and only 1 fits `ruseSet == "set3"`, thus you have the rule triggered only once.

**Test 1 (InputObject)**

```
@DroolsSession(resources = "draft/inputObjectExample.xlsx",
        builderProperties = "drools.dump.dir = target/dump",
        showStateTransitionPopup = true)
public class PlaygroundTest extends DroolsAssert {
    
    @RegisterExtension
    public DroolsAssert droolsAssert = this;
    
    @Test
    @TestRules(expectedCount = { "1", "Check_DyrAlder" })
    public void testInputObjectExample() {
        KieCommands commandFactory = KieServices.get().getCommands();
        List<Command<?>> commands = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            InputObject inputObject = new InputObject();
            inputObject.setTransactionId(i);
            inputObject.setRuleSet("set" + i);
            inputObject.setInput(ImmutableMap.of("DyrAlder", i));
            inputObject.setValidationResults(new ArrayList<>());
            
            commands.add(commandFactory.newInsert(inputObject, "ValRes"));
            commands.add(commandFactory.newFireAllRules());
        }
        
        commands.forEach(c -> getSession().execute(c));
    }
}
```

**Decision table**

[image]

**Generated rule**

```
package draft;
//generated from Decision Table
import draft.InputObject;
import draft.ValidationResult;
// rule values at A9, header at A4
rule "Check_DyrAlder"
    when
        animal:InputObject(ruleSet == "set3", input["DyrAlder"] < 5)
    then
        animal.addValidationResult(new ValidationResult("HDY-08277", "message"));
end
```

**Model**

```
public class InputObject {
    private Integer primaryKey;
    private Integer sessionId;
    private Integer transactionId;
    private String ruleSet;
    private Map<String, Object> input;
    private List<ValidationResult> validationResults;
    // getters/setters
```

---

**Test 2 (DroolsObject)**

```
@DroolsSession(resources = "draft/droolsObjectExample.xlsx",
        builderProperties = "drools.dump.dir = target/dump",
        showStateTransitionPopup = true)
public class PlaygroundTest extends DroolsAssert {
    
    @RegisterExtension
    public DroolsAssert droolsAssert = this;
    
    @Test
    @TestRules(expectedCount = { "1", "Check_DyrAlder" })
    public void testDroolsObjectExample() {
        KieCommands commandFactory = KieServices.get().getCommands();
        List<Command<?>> commands = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            DroolsObject inputObject = new DroolsObject();
            inputObject.put("ruleSet", "set" + i);
            inputObject.put("DyrAlder", i);
            
            commands.add(commandFactory.newInsert(inputObject, "ValRes"));
            commands.add(commandFactory.newFireAllRules());
        }
        
        commands.forEach(c -> getSession().execute(c));
    }
}
```

**Decision table**

[image]

**Generated rule**

```
package draft;
//generated from Decision Table
import draft.DroolsObject;
import draft.ValidationResult;
// rule values at A9, header at A4
rule "Check_DyrAlder"
    when
        animal:DroolsObject(ruleSet == "set3", DyrAlder < 5)
    then
        animal.addValidationResult(new ValidationResult("HDY-08277", "message"));
end
```

**Model**

```
public class DroolsObject extends LinkedHashMap<String, Object> {
    public void addValidationResult(ValidationResult validationResult) {
        if (!this.containsKey("validationResult"))
            this.put("validationResult", new LinkedList<ValidationResult>());
        ((List<ValidationResult>) this.get("validationResult")).add(validationResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this does work when deployed to my Drools-WorkBench. I have some issue regarding your testcase (this is probably me getting confused regarding classpath). But for your test2 example, I get a nullpointer exception in the Lambda function `commands.forEach(c -> getSession().execute(c));` in the testcase, with the following structure `MyProj>src>test>java>draft>[DroolsObject.java, droolsObjectExample.xlsx, PlaygroundTest.java, ValidationResult.java]`

Also you should probably add that the testcase was created using [Droolsassert](https://github.com/droolsassert/droolsassert)

Comment: Hi Asger, getSession() will return null if session was not initialized. Did you omit `@DroolsSession` or `@RegisterExtension` annotations?

Comment: Hi @mike, it is `getSession()` that returns null in this case. I did not omit either `@DroolsSession` nor `@RegisterExtension`. I literally just copy-pasted your examples in your answer, to see if I could narrow down what my issue was with the testcase. Though this did not solve it. Maybe I should just submit an Issue to the github for DroolsAssert?

Comment: do you start it as junit5 test? Could you describe your environment, how do you run it?

Comment: I found the solution.
If you are curious about where I failed, as I don't know how much of it was me being goofy with my class path, and how much would've been a dependency for Droolsassert that was missing. You can find my minimum drools example here; [https://github.com/asger-weirsoee/drools-minimum-example](https://github.com/asger-weirsoee/drools-minimum-example) where the solution is the difference between the initial commit and the commit afterwards